# Install add-in with Document Open function in dotm template

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to deploy my addin with custom ribbon for a group of users.
To be able to auto update the tool for all my users i have created a Tool-Loader.dotm add-in. This add-in will be stored in the user C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP\ folder.
When the user is starting Word it should enable the real addin which is placed on a networkshare.
This way my users wont have to worry about updates because i only have to replace the read add-in on my networkshare. When the users restart Word is should reload the add-in and people are up to date.

I have added the following code to my Tool-Loader.dotm in STARTUP folder:
ThisDocument:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Document_New()

Dim addinpath As String
addinpath = "\\[NETWORK SHARE]\Tool.dotm"

If Dir(addinpath) <> "" Then
    AddIns.Add FileName:=addinpath, Install:=True
Else
    MsgBox "Cant load Tool. Please check network connection and VPN")
End If

End Sub
```

I did the same for :
Private Sub Document_Open()

It works fine when opening the Tool-Loader.dotm file directly. But it is not working when placing the file in the STARTUP folder and normally starting Word.

How can i fix thix problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Document_New` and `Document_Open` only work for documents and document templates. A template placed in the Startup folder is termed a "global template" (Normal.dotm is also a global template). Global templates are loaded, not opened.

As there isn't an OnLoad event for a template we have to look for alternatives. If the global template contains a ribbon the ribbon's OnLoad event can be used. Otherwise we have to go old school and use an `AutoExec` routine, placed in a standard module.

Documentation for the Auto Macros can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/auto-macros)

```
Public Sub AutoExec()
    
  Dim addinpath As String
  addinpath = "\\[NETWORK SHARE]\Tool.dotm"
    
  If Dir(addinpath) <> "" Then
    AddIns.add FileName:=addinpath, Install:=True
  Else
    MsgBox "Cant load Tool. Please check network connection and VPN"
  End If
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Thank you!</strike> Based on your answer i am going to add a ribbon to my Tool-Loader and try to use the OnLoad event.

If that doesnt work i will try the AutoExec

Update for people having the same issue:
With the Custom UI Editor i added the following lines of code:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="LoadAddin">
</customUI>
```

Then i opened the Tool-Loader.dotm file and placed the following code in ThisDocument:

```
Dim MyRibbon As IRibbonUI
 
Sub LoadAddin(Ribbon As IRibbonUI)
On Error Resume Next
Set MyRibbon = Ribbon
 
Dim addinpath As String
addinpath = "[networkshare]"

If Dir(addinpath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
MsgBox "Can't load addin, please check internetconnection and VPN."
Exit Sub
Else
    AddIns.Add FileName:=addinpath & "Tool.dotm", Install:=True
End If

End Sub
```

Now it works and when opening Word the latest version of the tool is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I too use a tool loader to deploy a network shared dotm. I keep my Ribbon in the main file though, not in the tool loader.

I make sure the user has their wdWorkgroupTemplatesPath set to the network location where the main addin is kept. The tooloader then uses autoexec to call the below Addin-loader, if it doesn't find the Addin in word's list of addins it falls back to loading it from the file on the network drive.

```
Public Sub AutoExec()
        Call LoadAddin
End Sub

Public Sub LoadAddin()
    Dim vAddin As Variant
    Dim bLoaded As Boolean
    Dim strWorkgoupTemplatesPath As String
    
    bLoaded = False
    
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        For Each vAddin In Application.AddIns
            If ADDINNAME = vAddin.Name Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                vAddin.Installed = True
                bLoaded = True
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
        Next vAddin
        
LoadFromFile:
    If Not bLoaded Then
        strWorkgoupTemplatesPath = Options.DefaultFilePath(Path:=wdWorkgroupTemplatesPath)
        Call InstallMainAddin(strWorkgoupTemplatesPath)
    End If
    
ExitHandler:
       Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
  bLoaded = False
  If Err.Number = 4706 Then GoTo LoadFromFile
  GoTo ExitHandler

End Sub


Function InstallMainAddin(strWorkgoupTemplatesPath As String) As Boolean
    Dim bResult As Boolean
    Dim vMainAddin As Variant

    On Error Resume Next
    SetAttr strWorkgoupTemplatesPath & ADDINNAME, vbReadOnly
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set vMainAddin = Application.AddIns.Add(strWorkgoupTemplatesPath & ADDINNAME)
    vMainAddin.Installed = True
  
    bResult = True
ExitHandler:
       Application.DisplayAlerts = True
       InstallMainAddin = bResult
       Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
       bResult = False
       GoTo ExitHandler

End Function
```